# ServiceUnavailableHttpException on front end, and 404 on admin

Tags: craft3, valet

Trying to get started with Craft CMS 3 for the first time, and it's running locally via Valet. from the front end, I get:

> ```
> > HTTP 503 – Service Unavailable – craft\web\ServiceUnavailableHttpException
> ```

And on the admin side, I'm getting a 404. I've looked at similar questions, but none of the answers are helping me. I've set this up twice following [this article on running Craft with Valet](https://medium.com/@jalendport/running-craft-cms-3-on-laravel-valet-6df61e5193fd), and gotten the same result both times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it was because I had Apache running and on port 80. I saw something about this somewhere in the guides I followed, but forgot to come back and stop Apache. Oops.

Comment: Hey  I wrote the article you linked in your question. Glad you solved the issue!

Comment: @JalenDavenport Woo, big thanks for that article! Helped a lot, since the other ways were dead ends.